# NLP Classification / Inference on Small Dataset -> Word Embedding Approach

Tags: python, nlp

I would like to create a model that is given a series of keywords extracted from the description about a company and classifies the 'type' of the company. Let me illustrate with an example.

> "Snapchat is an image messaging and multimedia mobile application created by Evan Spiegel, Bobby Murphy, and Reggie Brown,[3] former students at Stanford University, and developed by Snap Inc., originally Snapchat Inc. "
>
> > Sample Extracted Keywords: "image messaging" ; "multimedia mobile application"
>
> (from Wikipedia page on Snapchat)

Given this info, my model will need to infer 'IT' and 'SNS' from "image messaging" and "multimedia mobile application".

(In case you are asking why not go with the extracted keywords, I would like to categorize them into as few labels as possible for all companies, so 'IT' and 'SNS' are more general terms compared to 'image messaging' and such.)

Currently, my dataset is not too big. For about hundreds of data entries, about ~80 % contain info in the manner that I want. Given this info, I would like to process the keywords extracted from descriptions about the company and give them correct labels.

Any suggestions to aid me in this project would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are targeting companies of specific domains, then using a small dataset may help you. So, one approach you may follow:

Use pre-trained word embeddings (ex. from [Glove](http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/)) of the extracted keywords and find a embedding for companies. It will be like constructing phrase or sentence representation from word embeddings. Lets name it company embeddings! Similar type of companies should have a similar embedding. So, ultimate idea is to form a relationship like `Google - Ford = Microsoft - Tesla` which we see in word embeddings. You can even think of other interesting arithmetic relations using embeddings, for example, `Google = search engine + youtube + android` where right-hand-side terms are extracted keywords.

You need `company type` information for further classification but that should be very simple enough using any machine learning classifier. You can use a simple text classifier to accomplish your overall goal but it would be interesting to achieve this using NLP techniques.